# How is methane removed from the atmosphere?

Tags: organic-chemistry, atmospheric-chemistry

I am not a chemist, but I've studied anthropology, geology, and history for decades. Obviously, my reason for asking this community is climate change. Specifically the concept of the methane ice on the sea floor melting and exponentially increasing warming.

What is the mechanism that brought all of that methane down to the sea floor in the first place? As I understand, methane is quite light and doesn't react with $\ce{H2O},$ or $\ce{O2},$ or $\ce{CO2}.$ Does it react with the photons over time and become reactive and sink?

Comment: Think of it under the water column pressure and bottom temperature. . It should be methane that formed as natural gas, there - is not really methane sinking from the atmosphere to the ocean bottom.

Comment: Methane **does** react with H2O to form methane hydrates, given the right conditions.

Comment: Oh, okay, so the seafloor methane wasn't sunk down from the atmosphere sometime before the pleistocene, when things were a lot hotter. Thank you for that, that's really cool information. That still doesn't answer the question of how atmospheric methane can be bound into the ground. I know t

Comment: I think methane forms through the (bacterial?) degradation of organic matter. In some stinking still waters you can poke holes in underwater bubbles with a stick and light the gas as it reaches the surface.

Comment: Methane does oxidate, and this is probably how it is removed from the atmosphere. Perhaps it is catalized somehow (by light or by specific compounds). It can oxidate to methanol, or entirely degraded to H2O & CO2. It can also be biologically anaerobically oxidized with nitrite.

Comment: Methane reacts with the hydroxyl radical (OH$\cdot$) in the atmosphere, and the new radical produced then reacts with oxygen; see the Wikipedia page .

Comment: I'm confused by "That still doesn't answer the question of how atmospheric methane can be bound into the ground." Do you have an example of methane being bound into the ground from the atmosphere? Generally, methane that is now below ground was never in the atmosphere. Methane in the atmosphere is removed by chemical or biological oxidation, so it does not end up as below-ground methane.

Comment: I'd take a look [at the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane_clathrate#Oceanic) article on the topic and links from there. There is no direct connection between methane in the atmosphere and that in the deep sea, other then oil exploration and maybe natural emissions resulting in atmospheric methane originating from "oceanic deposits".

Answer (score 3):

Per a source discussing the [Methane Cycle](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/education/info_activities/pdfs/CTA_the_methane_cycle.pdf), apparently it is slowly removed on average of approximately 9 years as a consequent of sunlight-induced radical activity. To quote:

> The main mechanism for removal of methane from the earth’s atmosphere is oxidation within the troposphere by the hydroxyl radical (OH).

that reaction is given by:

$\ce{CH4 + .OH -> .CH3 + H2O}$

with the formation of the transient methyl radical which subsequently can interact with, for example, O2 leading to formaldehyde, water vapor, and eventually possibly CO2. The reaction chains are long and provided in this [Wikipedia commentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_methane).

The second sink for methane is the chlorine radical:

$\ce{CH4 + .Cl -> .CH3 + HCl}$

The associated source of radicals is strong UV light found in the upper atmosphere acting on water vapor, for example.

Per the cited Methane Cycle article, ascribed sources of methane are attributed to:

> It is estimated that up to 60% of the current methane flux from land to the atmosphere is the result of human activities. Some of these activities include emissions from fermentation processes associated with livestock, from cultivated rice paddies, from fossil fuel use and biomass burning, and from landfills.